# Parent Page Controls are inactive when setting overlayclose to false in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

It seems, I am missing something on colorbox.
I want to disable overlayclose effect. By setting overlayClose: false, I made it to disable it. But the problem arised when I tried to click a text box or button on the parent page (the page from where colorbox generated).

It seems that the controls are disabled. I tried to remove z-index element from #cboxoverlay css, but to no result.

Could anyone please throw some light on that.
Help appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: Hi Suhajit, please illustrate a bit more.

Comment: @J.Chomel -- i have a page. from that page i have a hyperlink which essentially opens the colorbox, an external page via ajax. Now the colorbox which opens has a property overlayClose. A/C to docs, if set to false, the colorbox would not close on ovelay clicks. Thats fine and i managed to do that. But what arised as an issue is that in the main page, from which I opened the colorbox, doesnot respond to any events, say, some activity on a textbox is not possible. What I need is that I want to operate on the main page like submiting the form

Comment: Does setting trapFocus to false make it work?